# Fatal error using `RWeka::NGramTokenizer` with `tm` to build a term document matrix?

Tags: r, text-mining, weka, parallel-computing

I installed the `tm` library and want to build n-grams of a corpus using the `NGramTokenizer` from the `RWeka` library.

The `tm` [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper) p. 11 lists the following call:

```
> TermDocMatrix(col, control=list(tokenize = NGramTokenizer))
```

I know I need to use `TermDocumentMatrix` in the version of `tm` I'm using. I get the following return:

```
> col
A corpus with 3 text documents
>
> TermDocumentMatrix(col, control=list(tokenize=NGramTokenizer))
#  fatal error: mach_msg (send) failed: 0x10000003

#  fatal error: mach_msg (send) failed: 0x10000003

A term-document matrix (0 terms, 3 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 0/0
Sparsity           : NaN%
Maximal term length: 0 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Warnmeldung:
In is.na(x) :
  is.na() auf nicht-(Liste oder Vektor) des Typs 'NULL' angewendet
```

What could be the problem here? The corpus is not that large (truncated for testing).

```
> print(object.size("col"))
96 bytes
```

Comment: I'd be happy to answer by explaining how to do this in the **quanteda** package (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281534/generating-all-word-unigrams-through-trigrams-in-r), but you did ask specifically how to do it in **tm**. Let me know if you would find such an answer helpful.

Comment: I would find it useful.

Comment: OK done, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot quickly see what would generate your error without having a sample data set. But if you run the following code you can see that the RWeka tokonizer works.

```
  library(tm)
  library(RWeka)

  data("crude")
  crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
  crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
  crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
  crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  crude <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument)
  # Sets the default number of threads to use
  options(mc.cores=1)

  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control=list(tokenize = NGramTokenizer))

  findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 10)

[1] "accord"      "barrel"      "bpd"         "crude"       "crude oil"   "dlrs"        "dlrs barrel" "futur"       "govern"      "kuwait"      "last"       
[12] "market"      "meet"        "mln"         "mln bpd"     "month"       "new"         "offici"      "oil"         "oil price"   "one"         "opec"       
[23] "pct"         "price"       "prices"      "product"     "reuter"      "said"        "saudi"       "say"         "sheikh"      "u s"         "will"       
[34] "world"       "year"
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example:
>   crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
>   crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
Warnmeldung:
In parallel::mclapply(x, FUN, ...) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

Comment: Ah, I have seen that mentioned before. RWeka and parallel apparently have some errors working together. See also this post on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703553/bigrams-instead-of-single-words-in-termdocument-matrix-using-r-and-rweka.
I have adjusted a line of code that should help.

Answer (score 7):

OK, here is the method for tokenizing grams in **quanteda**.  Our view is that there is no such thing as *n*-grams without tokenization, since the notion implies sequences of tokens defined by some kind of adjacency.  So we built in an `ngrams` option into our `tokenize()` function.  `ngrams` takes a vector of integers, where each integer represents a size of ngram (the default is `1`).

It works like this:

```
> # or: devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda")
> require(quanteda)
> mytext <- c("The quick brown fox, jumped over the lazy dog.",
+             "Here is a second sentence to tokenize.")
> tokenize(toLower(mytext), removePunct = TRUE, ngrams = 2)
[[1]]
[1] "the_quick"   "quick_brown" "brown_fox"   "fox_jumped"  "jumped_over" "over_the"    "the_lazy"   
[8] "lazy_dog"   

[[2]]
[1] "here_is"         "is_a"            "a_second"        "second_sentence" "sentence_to"     "to_tokenize"    

attr(,"class")
[1] "tokenizedTexts" "list"          
> tokenize(toLower(mytext), removePunct = TRUE, ngrams = 3)
[[1]]
[1] "the_quick_brown"  "quick_brown_fox"  "brown_fox_jumped" "fox_jumped_over"  "jumped_over_the" 
[6] "over_the_lazy"    "the_lazy_dog"    

[[2]]
[1] "here_is_a"            "is_a_second"          "a_second_sentence"    "second_sentence_to"  
[5] "sentence_to_tokenize"

attr(,"class")
[1] "tokenizedTexts" "list"          
> tokenize(toLower(mytext), removePunct = TRUE, ngrams = 1:3)
[[1]]
 [1] "the"              "quick"            "brown"            "fox"              "jumped"          
 [6] "over"             "the"              "lazy"             "dog"              "the_quick"       
[11] "quick_brown"      "brown_fox"        "fox_jumped"       "jumped_over"      "over_the"        
[16] "the_lazy"         "lazy_dog"         "the_quick_brown"  "quick_brown_fox"  "brown_fox_jumped"
[21] "fox_jumped_over"  "jumped_over_the"  "over_the_lazy"    "the_lazy_dog"    

[[2]]
 [1] "here"                 "is"                   "a"                    "second"              
 [5] "sentence"             "to"                   "tokenize"             "here_is"             
 [9] "is_a"                 "a_second"             "second_sentence"      "sentence_to"         
[13] "to_tokenize"          "here_is_a"            "is_a_second"          "a_second_sentence"   
[17] "second_sentence_to"   "sentence_to_tokenize"

attr(,"class")
[1] "tokenizedTexts" "list"          
> 
> # to create a dfm from one of these
> mytokTxts <- tokenize(toLower(mytext), removePunct = TRUE, ngrams = 3)
> dfm(mytokTxts)
Creating a dfm from a tokenizedTexts object ...
   ... indexing 2 documents
   ... shaping tokens into data.table, found 12 total tokens
   ... summing tokens by document
   ... indexing 12 feature types
   ... building sparse matrix
   ... created a 2 x 12 sparse dfm
   ... complete. Elapsed time: 0.023 seconds.
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 12 features.
2 x 12 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
       features
docs    a_second_sentence brown_fox_jumped fox_jumped_over here_is_a is_a_second jumped_over_the over_the_lazy
  text1                 0                1               1         0           0               1             1
  text2                 1                0               0         1           1               0             0
       features
docs    quick_brown_fox second_sentence_to sentence_to_tokenize the_lazy_dog the_quick_brown
  text1               1                  0                    0            1               1
  text2               0                  1                    1            0               0
```

Happy to help further if you have more questions.

**UPDATED 2021 w/quanteda v3**

Here's how to do it with a less ancient version of **quanteda**:

````r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0.
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

mytext <- c(
  "The quick brown fox, jumped over the lazy dog.",
  "Here is a second sentence to tokenize."
)

tokens(mytext, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_tolower() %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 2) %>%
  dfm()
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 14 features (50.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##        features
## docs    the_quick quick_brown brown_fox fox_jumped jumped_over over_the
##   text1         1           1         1          1           1        1
##   text2         0           0         0          0           0        0
##        features
## docs    the_lazy lazy_dog here_is is_a
##   text1        1        1       0    0
##   text2        0        0       1    1
## [ reached max_nfeat ... 4 more features ]
```
````